# Is setContentView() needed to inflate a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to set up a setting page for my app by following the [Settings guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=en).

I followed the code in the MySettingsActivity, but without `setContentView()` the app crashes with the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800d5 (com.example.wifilogger:id/settings_container) for fragment SettingsFragment
```

Here is my code

SettingsActivity.kt

```
package com.example.wifilogger

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)   // Comment this out will crash
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

activity_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity" />
```

SettingsFragment.kt

```
package com.example.wifilogger

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat

class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

I looked up the Internet. Some tutorials used `setContentView()` but some don't. So, when do I need to use `setContentView()`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when do I need to use setContentView()?

Any time you have an `Activity` that you want to display UI, you must call `setContentView()`.

For an `Activity` that hosts `Fragment`s, you still need to call `setContentView()` so that you can have something to put the Fragments inside of (e.g. `R.id.settings_container` will be part of the activity's content view).

> I followed the code in the MySettingsActivity, but without setContentView() the app crashes with the following error.

It is either an outright mistake in that tutorial, or they simply omitted it for brevity.

> Some tutorials used `setContentView()` but some don't.

Again, for `Activity`, you would only **not** use `setContentView()` if you didn't want your activity to display anything (maybe it starts up to handle some `Intent` but then finishes itself immediately).

For `Fragment`, the view is created by overriding `onCreateView()` and returning a view, rather than by calling `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.layout_file_id)` is used to fill out activity window with layout indicated by passed XML layout id. Obviously, if you dont set content view for your main activity layout, the fragment manager will not know what is `settings_container` in this statment:

```
supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
        .commit()
```